# How can I make socketio close connection immediately on page refresh?

Tags: socket.io, flask-socketio

I have implemented a chat service but it seems if a user keeps refreshing the page fast enough it can connect to itself. It is not exactly itself but the id of its previous session. Issue happens because on fast refreshes browser does not trigger io.disconnect. I have tried to solve it by attaching disconnect code to onbeforeunload event but it doesn't make much change. I don't want to fiddle with pingtimeout and pinginterval because those might interfere with reconnection abilities. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mistaken. Those duplicate connections will be disconnected eventually. For connections that are established with the polling protocol it takes about a minute to detect a disconnected client.